# Some assistance with a Delete LINQ expression please

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to write a LINQ query to maintain a distinct list of suppliers

```
Order
  - SupplierId


UniqueSupplierList
  - Id
  - SupplierId
```

Example

```
Order
   Supplier1
   Supplier1
   Supplier2

UniqueSupplierList
   1, Supplier1
   2, Supplier2
```

Now if I change Order3 so that:

```
Order
   Supplier1
   Supplier1
   Supplier1
```

I would need to delete UniqueSupplierList, record 2, to produce

```
UniqueSupplierList
   1, Supplier1
```

This is the delete I am struggling with and require help for. I realise the example is a little contrived, but it is the delete LINQ sample I am interested in.

There is no foreign key between the tables.

In SQL I might do something like:

```
delete from UniqueSupplierList where supplierid not in (Select SupplierId from Order where...)
```

Some LINQ code to start with:

```
db.UniqueSupplierList.Where(r.SupplierId!=????).ToList().ForEach(db.UniqueSupplierList.DeleteObject);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you also have an `Orders` collection in your database. In which case:

```
var supplierIDs = db.Orders.Select(o => o.SupplierID).Distinct();
var toDelete = db.UniqueSupplierList.Where(usl => !supplierIDs.Contains(usl.SupplierID)).ToList();

toDelete.ForEach(td => db.UniqueSupplierList.Remove(td));

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Just implemented this and it works great. I guess I was trying to do everything in one line !! But thank you, really appreciated.

Comment: Just because you can sometimes do things is one line does not mean you necessarily should. I think that this way is better because it's more clear as to what you're trying to do.